# Laravel ajax request not working

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.1

I followed some of the tutorial to do ajax call in Laravel5 , Following is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ajaxc').on('click',function(){
        var url=$('#url').val();
        var _token= $('#csrf').val();
        alert(_token);
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:url,
                data:{_token:_token,email:'admin@gmail.com',password:'123456'},
                sucess: function(data){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        }
    });

});
});
</script>

<div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" id="url" value="{{ action('LoginController@postLogin') }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <button type="button" id="ajaxc" class="btn btn-error btn-quirk btn-block">Sign In</button>
        </div>
```

But I am getting `internal server error 500`

Any ide where I could be wrong

The route for this is

```
//POST route
Route::post('home', 'LoginController@postLogin');
```

Any help would be appriciated

Thanks

Comment: Check the logs, you'll see there why you're getting error 500.

Comment: Please provide more information on how you have Laravel hosted? Your web server configuration. Does Laravel work fine, for any other route?